# Creating a custom decorator for validating date intervals

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator, class-validator

I'm trying to create a decorator using TS to check if a date is between 2 intervals.

Normally I would use something like @Min() and @Max() decorators from class-validators.
But they're not working on this case since data gets transformed in some sort of way, and it makes the decorator fail everytime.

[image]

Comment: If the interval is static, you can use `@MinDate` and `@MaxDate`

Comment: @CodyTseng
Yes that is possible, but data gets sent as a string on this format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
Which will cause it to always fail.

Comment: You need to use `@Type(() => Date)`. And the `ValidationPipe` need to set `transform: true`.

Comment: @CodyTseng
Thanks this works now after your advice.
I shouldn't have had that @IsDateString() decorator also.